# img src didnt show in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I here my code, I create a component and its got a slot inside it, I want to passing the image url into <img /> with v-bind:src but the image didn't showed up on the docs, nor there is no error in console.

```
<MyComp v-if="myData.length"> 
    <template #img> 
        <div class="my-slot"> 
            <img :src="myData.image"/> 
        </div> 
    </template> 
</MyComp>

data () {
    return {
        myData: [
              {
                image: "https://www...."
              },
              {
                image: "https://www...."
              },
              {
                image: "https://www...."
              }
    }
}
```

Wondering did I miss something? I couldn't use new URL or require too. The static url on tag  also didnt work.

Comment: Yes but doesnt work, Im sorry it was a typo already edit the code above,

Comment: And i didn't notice it was an object, not a path. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to use `scoped-slot`. Pass `myData` as prop in your parent component and use `scoped-slot` to pass url in `:src`

Example:

```
<template>
  <MyComp v-if="myData.length" :images="myData">
    <template #img="{ image }">
      <div class="my-slot">
        <img :src="image"/>
      </div>
    </template>
  </MyComp>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      myData: [
        {
          image: 'https://www....',
        },
        {
          image: 'https://www....',
        },
        {
          image: 'https://www....',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh the scoped-slot helped me a lot! Thank you in advance @igor

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `myData` variable is an array of objects, and you're referring to it as if it was simply an object:

```
<img :src="myData.image"/>
```

You should reference particular element of the array:

```
<img :src="myData[0].image"/>
```